# Can't get data from Stack Exchange API

Tags: php, json, curl, stackexchange-api

I am trying to get data from http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=php .

I am using this code to get data from the API:

```
$url = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=php";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($json);
```

But it is showing me nothing. I have also used curl to get the data, but it also shows nothing. Why isn't it showing me anything, and how can I fix that?

Comment: What do you get when you click the link?

Answer (score 3):

They are returning you gzipped content as response. That's why it didn't work with your json decoding. Here is equivalent curl request.

```
$url= "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ""); // this will handle gzip content
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print $result;
// do json processing here
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds :) But I can confirm that this works.

Answer (score 2):

The response is gzipped, use `gzdecode` :

```
$url = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=php";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode(gzdecode($json), true);
print_r($json);
```